# Image only shows when resized/selected

Tags: html, css

So i put up a video on our page http://playgrounddistribution.com

It worked like a charm, until i scrolled down and saw that the image behind the "ABOUT US" section doesn't show until i select it with cmd+a or resize the window. This is rather annoying because the text is white so if the background isn't there you can't read it.

At first i thought the video loaded before the image, so i tried only loading metadata, but that didn't solve the problem. Then i figured it must be the cache, but disabling the cache didn't solve it either. Then i noticed selecting it or resizing the window did the trick, but that isn't optimal for our customers. It only seems to occur in Chrome. Have any of you experienced this problem before or should i include the css?

Screenshots here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUvnR.jpg

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Works just fine here in Chrome 46 on OS X 10.11. Have you tried rebooting? http://dronelife.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/it-crowd-2.jpg

Comment: I haven't rebooted my own computer (10.11) but i tried it on a different mac running 10.10 also with Chrome 46 and it had the same problem (that had never accessed the site before). I flushed cache, disabled cache, but nothing seems to help. The only thing that helps is removing the fixed tag as suggested below but i like the fixed feature so would prefer if it could stay the same way. I have no idea why it's doing it. I liked the IT crowd reference though :)

Comment: What if you remove the fixed from the inline CSS and add background-attachment:fixed;  to the style.css?

Comment: Removed it and added the background-attachment:fixed; it didn't seem to solve it, but thank you for the suggestion. http://imgur.com/0Tn2Yre